# Tracing ca 1805 immigration via Port of Charleston, SC, USA from Germany?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, germany, immigration, south-carolina

My 4th great grandfather came into the USA via the Port of Charleston, SC as a bound boy, according to family history.

Is there any place to find information regarding this?

He arrived about the year of 1805 or so from Germany.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  People here may be able to help with a generic answer using the information provided but I think your question is likely to attract an answer sooner if you provide your 4th great grandfather's name (and any other information about him that you think may be helpful).  That way he could be used as a worked example.  Of course, you are under no obligation to provide his name.  There is an **edit** button beneath your question that enables you to do this if you wish.

Comment: It would also be useful to know what you've tried. For example have you looked at https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Charleston_County,_South_Carolina_Immigration, http://www.pricegen.com/immigrantservants/search/simple.php and http://www.germanroots.com/miscports/charleston.html